# How to call my function n times within another function

Tags: python

I am writing a filter function such that when I insert my wave number, which is a list of numbers, the filter_wave_num function will be executed n times to change the wave number.

However, it doesnt seem to work, it repeats the output only once, when I want it to do it n times. Will appreciate your help in this.

```
def filter_wave_num(wave):
    new_wave = []
    for i in range(len(wave)):
            if i == 0:
                new_wave.append(int(wave[i]*0.6 + wave[i+1]*0.2))
            elif i == len(wave)-1:
                new_wave.append(int(wave[i-1]*0.2 + wave[i]*0.6))
            else:
                new_wave.append(int(wave[i-1]*0.2 + wave[i]*0.6 + wave[i+1]*0.2))
    return new_wave

def filter_wave(wave,n):
    for i in range(n):
        filter_wave_num(wave)
    return filter_wave_num(wave)

wave = [600, 3200, 7600, 13400, 18400, 22600, 24400] 
# each element inside the list has to be changed n times
```

Comment: In your loop, the loop variable `i` is never used. Moreover, the return value of `filter_wave_num` is never used.

Comment: Why do you want to create 2 functions? Just create a single `filter_wave_num` function and create a loop inside it.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the second function. Why do you need to execute the `filter_wave_num` n times?

Comment: Basically, I have a list of numbers, which I need to modify with a filter function, based on this mathematical formula (wave[i-1]*0.2 + wave[i]*0.6 + wave[i+1]*0.2), do let me know if you can propose a better work around

Answer (score 2):

The `filter_wave_num` function works.

If you need to use it recursively n times (each time on the result obtained the previous time) modify your second function like this:

```
def filter_wave(wave, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        wave = filter_wave_num(wave)
    return wave
```

The function you have written creates each time a new list, but you don't return the result each iteration and it's lost.

Answer (score 1):

You do call your function n times, but you are calling it with the same input so you get the same output after all iterations.
Here's what you need to do:
Notice that I changed the name of 'i' to '_', this is a convention indicates we don't need to use the value of this variable

```
def filter_wave(wave,n):
    result = wave
    for _ in range(n):
        result = filter_wave_num(result)
    return result
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it still returns the same output, it shows 1 time when its suppose to be n times, is there something wrong with my filter_wave_num function? I suspect, it had something to my new_wave = [] empty list assignment

Comment: You were right, I didn't passed the right parameter to the function.
I edited my comment, now it suppose to work

Comment: Thanks its working now, still trying to understand what is the difference between my filter_wave function compared to yours, is it because I did not declare a local variable in my function?

Comment: You didn't change the input you inserted to 'filter_wave_num',
What I did is in each iteration, I stored the result, and then passe the last result as the new input.
lets say you have a function f(x) = x + 1,
what you did is like calling f(1) 5 times and what I did is changing the input in each iteration, so the first time its f(1) the second time is f(f(1)) the third time is f(f(f(1))) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Store all the iteration results in a list and then return it:

```
def filter_wave(wave,n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        wave = filter_wave_num(wave)
        result.append(wave)
    return result
```